# Wordpress - Add validation to First and Last name

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce

I've been stuck on, in my opinion, a very simple and stupid problem. In the Wordpress User Backend, you have a First and Last name field. The only thing I want to accomplish is to add some form of validation to these fields. I also want to prevent Users from adding numbers to their first and last names in their WooCommerce account.

**The problem**

I cannot allow any numbers in the First and Last name fields, since WooCommerce uses this field for billing and shipping, and I use these fields for other purposes as well. I do not want to use plugins for this, and would like to accomplish this programmatically.

( BTW, it's also absolutely ridiculous even trying to Google this very problem. The only results are about custom fields and plugins, plugins, plugins... And the worst thing, is that none of those actually serve this purpose )

**What I have tried**

I have tried looking trough WP's admin user code, but I can't make heads or tails of it. I've seen ( a lot of ) suggestions about using plugins and using Custom Fields, but I don't want a plugin to do this for me, because of WooCommerce. I 'simply' want to add a validation to these 2 fields to prevent numbers in these fields.

**Example of Checkout validation**

Below is a code snippet that adds registration validation for a custom field. I was wondering if I could use this for the first and last name fields as well. I would like to use this for both the User registration form on the front-end, and the Wordpress back-end.

```
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors','wooc_validate_custom_field', 10, 1 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors','wooc_validate_custom_field', 10, 1 );

function wooc_validate_custom_field( $args )
{
    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
    {
        if(preg_match('~[0-9]+~',$_POST['first_name'])) // if value contains a number
        $args->add( 'error', __( 'Numbers not allowed', 'woocommerce' ),'');
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this? *without* using plugins please.. :)

Comment: Please read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/) before you create code that rejects names that WordPress core doesn't reject.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but there is no alternative to this from a project scope perspective since I have multiple connected systems. It's regrettably, not up to me ... :')

Comment: Aha. Then it's Falsehoods Managers Believe About Names. Sigh.